# How aright use globals elements

Tags: php

Good day.

I have problems when i use globals element in some files which include in one file.

Structure my files you can see down:

**Files:**

```
-index.php
--function.php
--globals.php
--lang.php
--allfunction.php
```

Code all pages you can see down:

**Code index.php:**

```
<?
session_start();
require_once("./function.php");

select();

?>
```

**Code function.php:**

```
<?php
require_once("./globals.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/lang.php");
include_once Language(3);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/allfunction.php");
?>
```

**Code globals.php:**

```
<?
$dirang = './';
$langfile = 'lang.php';
$test = 'hello';
}
?>
```

**Code lang.php:**

```
<?  
Language($rem){
return $GLOBALS["langfile"]; //ex.
}
?>
```

**Code allfunction.php:**

```
<?  
echo $GLOBALS["test"]; //ex.
}
?>
```

I get problrem when i use `$GLOBALS["test"]` in `allfunction.php`.

I get error `Undefened index test in allfunction.php on line ....`

***Tell me please why i get it error and how aright use global element in `allfunction.php` ?***

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: The most correct usage of global variables: is to not use them at all.

Comment: @meagar can write global in one file an than use theys in other file?

P.S.: for ex., 
`
require_once("./globals.php");
require_once("./function.php"); //use globals here `

Comment: @zerkms really think it? when i use global I can reduce my time in the development of

Comment: @Teop Lome: when you build a house - don't create a foundation. It can reduce the time of building and overall cost. When you're preparing a salad - don't cut your vegetables - it also saves some time.

Comment: @zerkms ok, i have 90 000 lines code and i use global element 25-50 times in all codes. if me need change value it elements me need open file with globals and change only one value - value global element. if i do not use global me need find and change all 25-50 values in 90 000 lines code. find and change 50 values in 90 000 line will be very nice =)

Comment: I Guess you need some kind of config, not globals. Hint: Better use constants than globals, constants once set cannot be accidentally ovveriden.

Comment: @Teop Lome: "i have 90 000 lines code" --- it should be "I have 90 000 lines of crappy code". But anyway, it's very common when a newbie justifies terrible code by "reducing development time" (which in fact is just lack of experience)

Comment: @zerkms may be you are aright, but you not said why not need use globals in code? I will be very grateful for your response.

Comment: @Teop Lome: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/148109 and hundreds of other useful topics on "why globals are bad" google request

Comment: @zerkms thanks, i did not know before about all the shortcomings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write globals inside file where you use theys, for ex. if globals you use in `allfunction.php` you must write global variables in this file(in which you use them)
Not use a separate file with global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use globals. Store your variables in static `Config` or `Registry` class instead. Also have a read about [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Example:

`config.php`

```
<?php
class Config
{
    static $var1 = '...';
    static $var2 = '...';

    public static function init()
    {
        self::$var2 = 1+1; //expressions go here
    }
}
Config::init();
```

`usage.php`

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
function x()
{
    $someKindOfSetting = Config::$var1;
}
```

Comment: What you have posted has nothing to do with singleton. It's the same global variables (implemented as public static properties)

Comment: I know that. However, for me it doesn't really make difference whether I use static properties `X::$x` or refer to single instance `X::getInstance()->x` in this particular use case. That's why I provided both some code that does the trick and linked to article that explains how to implement it differently (not necessarily better, imo singleton is an anti-pattern).

Comment: Also no matter how you look at it, storing these "globals" in one place simplifies their management and allows things like easy (de)serialization etc.